# block ip cloudflare firewall rules, to block all countries but two

Tags: ip, cloudflare

I'm setting up my cloudflare account. I'd like to block all countries ip but not peru and bolivia.

In buttons context...I did the the following:

```
   country not equal to Peru and country not equal to Bolivia, block
```

I dont know if correct, though.

```
  (ip.geoip.country ne "BO" and ip.geoip.country ne "PE")
```

I put this expressions but I dont actually know if correct. which one to use `OR` or `AND`?

**Expect**

```
block everything, but Perú and Bolivia.
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use cloudflare, but looks like you want to use AND here. If the country is not equal to Bolivia AND it is also not equal to Peru, then block it.

### Why Can't you Use OR?

You asked in a commend why you can't use OR. The reason is because you're negating the equals, you need to use OR. It boils down to boolean logic. If you used country not equal Peru OR country not equal Bolivia, then you would end up blocking everything. To see why, let's examine the logic that would emerge from using OR:

- If the country is Peru, then it would be blocked simply because it's not Bolivia
- If the country is Bolivia, then it would be blocked simply because it's not Peru
- If the country is neither, then it will be blocked by virtue of not being either

This is clearly not what you want.

Comment: thank you. it works this way. I was wondering why using `AND` instead of  `OR`